# What is the most important thing (truth, lesson), you have learned so far in your Buddhist practice?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, questions

Being of a little Zen orientation I believe in a dialectical approach to the Buddhist practice,

Having an open conversation about your station on the journey to enlightenment will often correct your belief errors and point you in the right direction.

So if you want to share your experience please join me in a conversation.

PS - All beliefs and opinions are welcomed

 Hopefully this being a meta site the thought Gestapo will let us be :)

Comment: Please see [*"What is "meta"? How does it work?"*](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta): *"...Meta Buddhism Stack Exchange is the part of the site where users discuss the workings and policies of Buddhism Stack Exchange rather than discussing Buddhist philosophy, teaching, and practice itself..."*.

Comment: Where do you want to converse? A chat room is the best place for conversation. There are limits built-in to the other pages of the web site to discourage conversation (e.g. unlimited-length answers but limited-length comments, chronologically-sorted comments but not not chronologically-sorted answers).

Comment: Chat rooms are difficult to organize though ... they work best when people participate in real time, conversely a single Q&A topic (one question and a few people's answers) can happen in everyone's own time over the course of a day or so.

Comment: I tried to answer recently, what are 10 the best things I learned from this web site -- [see here](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/23313/254) -- if that's what you're asking about at all, though I guess it isn't.

Comment: Here's a chatty question for you: given what [you answered here](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/23657/254), what is a so-called "belief error"? What's the point of saying (i.e. teaching) that "Buddha is a state of mind" if you previously said that "all teachings are false teachings"? Can you describe (or otherwise point towards) that state of mind at all, for your own benefit or anyone else's? And isn't the outstanding characteristic of a Buddha that they're not only enlightened but also able to teach?

Comment: Let's say you wanna learn how to cook - You can A study a lot of cooking books or B enter as an apprentice to a master chef. A is academic learning B is practical learning. Buddha never taught or wrote a sutra or any other teachings neither his disciples or his disciples disciples. It took 500 years untill some Ego became so ignorant as to write it down and call it "Buddha's teachings". Those are the historical facts, not my own imagination. Enlightenment cannot be achieved academically. No matter how many cookbooks you read you'll never be a chef.

Comment: When they taught me how to cook, at *school*, what they taught me was how to read and understand (i.e. follow, obey, or execute) a written recipe (the first thing I made was a Christmas cake). Now I can cook (e.g. for myself and family), to the extent that I can perform according to a recipe or cook-book (and have some recipes memorised). I'm not a "chef" to the extent that I don't try to teach others, I don't cook different meals for dozens of people simultaneously, I don't have staff, and I don't experiment with creating new dishes.

Comment: Very good point So how is that recipe for enlightenment coming up?

Comment: I haven't met Zen teachers. My (superficial) reading of (popular) Zen literature suggests that "Are you enlightened?" is some kind of preoccupation or frequently-asked-question, is that so? Do they teach the four noble truths, or not really?

Comment: Is there a better way to communicate than this?

Comment: The word "enlightenment" might be one of those abstractions, intellectual conceptions or inchoate desires that you might warn against -- and a barrier rather than a recipe (see e.g. "To realize Zen one has to pass through the barrier of the patriarchs").

Comment: I'm having a problem with this damn thing. I keep hitting the return and cannot finish my thoughts

Comment: Yes, of course, study the 4NT but not as a way to enlightenment just a way to alleviate suffering.  How do you go about chatting?

Comment: Yup. There's no point in trying `<Shift><Return>` either, there's only limited formatting (no paragraphs) supported in comments. I can move these comments to chat (which would at least support `<Shift><Return>` if you'd want that; `<Return>` is still an implicit Send, though).

Comment: Ok I'm wide awake let's chat :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68139/discussion-on-question-by-buddha-hollywood-what-is-the-most-important-thing-tru).